# For VS Code notebooks, Is there a way to keep a notebook kernel alive when closing the file in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

For standard Jupyter Notebooks, if you close the browser and re-open later, the kernel will stay alive and you still have your variables. For VS Code however, I noticed as soon as you close the file, the kernel is gone. Is there a way to keep a kernel alive for the duration of the VS Code session?

Comment: does this issue ticket cover what you are looking for? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1378